# absolute sidebar taller than content clearfix?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having an issue. This is the code I have:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
#content {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 320px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}
#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">content</div>
  <div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>
</div>
<!--end wrapper-->
```

Overflow works great until `#sidebar` is lower than `#content`, but when `#sidebar` is taller it's cutting of part of my `#sidebar` content (obviously).

I was trying to set both of them to have tallest height but results were tragic - it was giving me some cosmic height of both (probably because one is absolute?)

I want to add a footer under both of them and I just can't figure it out.

When I'm adding the footer to clear both it's obviously clear floated element not absolute.

I could change `#sidebar` to float and use css calc for `#content` but it's not working in IE8.

I could use `$('#content').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=320px');` but it's not working ? Don't know why - it subtracts some value but not 320px

How should I do it?

Comment: what you want to achieve ? what kind of structure you want?

Comment: I want to put cleared footer under #wrapper even when absolute #sidebar is higher than floating #content.

Comment: Why not use absolute positioning on both inner elements of the wrapper and eliminate the float?

Comment: Actually, I think I see what you are aiming for now. This may be better suited for flex css.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not fixing my issue but thanks.

//edit
Flex is not working on ie8 & 9

Answer (score 1):

EDIT (Second Answer)

[Fiddle using display:table;](http://jsfiddle.net/geqqLcap/5/)

CSS

```
#header {
    background:orange;
}
#wrapper {
 display:table;
}
#content {
  display:table-cell;
  width:100%;
  background: red;
}
#sidebar {
 display:table-cell;
 background: green;
}

#sidebar-inner {
 width:300px;
}
#footer {
    background:blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">Content</div>
  <div id="sidebar">
      <div id="sidebar-inner">
        Sidebar  
      </div>      
  </div>  
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

Here is a solution via css flex. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geqqLcap/1/)

And here is another with more content and a header [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/geqqLcap/2/)

CSS

```
#wrapper {
  display:flex;
}
#content {
  flex-grow:1;
  background: red;
}
#sidebar {
  flex-grow:0;
  background: green;
  width: 300px;
}
#footer {
  background:blue;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="content">content</div>
  <div id="sidebar">sidebar</div>  
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

Comment: Thank you ViDesignz but flex is not working in IE8 and IE9 so that's not a solution for me.

Comment: Then you may have to use tables or set display as tables. Though IE 8 & 9 collectively account for only 1% of users...

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

Ok i figured out how to make it work.
I don't want do use this way of solution but i can't find anything else so:

If you having similar issue:

`#content` and `#sidebar` are on floats now.
 `#sidebar` have fixed width of `300px` and `#content` `100%`.

And i made this:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function () {
if ($(document).width() < 970) {
    var $left = $('#content_main');
    $left.css('width', '100%').width($left.width() - 320);
}
else {
    var $left = $('#content_main');
    $left.css('width', '970px').width($left.width() - 320);
}
```

});

Thanks to all for your interest, have a good day fellas.

Comment: Man, adding JS into it is completely unnecessary...to each his own though.

Comment: I did add a second solution to my answer, cross browser compatible.

Comment: Thanks again ViDesignz but i was trying do it on tables before and it did the trick at start but im working on much complex project and tables did not do the work after i filled them with content.

Thanks again for help.

Comment: Oh ok. I am not sure how my second solution would 'break' when content is added. Good luck though.